# How can I locate points on a path that are not smooth in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have drawn a number of shapes freehand on a graphics tablet in Adobe Illustrator. Most of these shapes are blob-like and almost all points on the paths are smooth. They'll show handles if selected, but the handles for each point should appear each 180° from each other.

However, some of the points did not render smoothly and will show up as corners if the point is selected, with the two handles for that point forming an angle.

I would like to be able to locate all of these corner points. Is there a way to select only such points? Barring that is there a way to detect them by looking at the svg data?

Answer (score 2):

With Javascript you could loop through the app paths and the points on the path then get the anchor point leftDirection and rightDirection then calculate the tangent angle. Then leave it selected or change the angle there in the loop.

Good Luck,

-Andy Stone

Edit: Sorry, "by looking at the SVG data"... I missed that. Not Sure.